# Anchor tags list creation

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, anchor

I am creating a list of anchor tags from a MySQL/PHP query; the anchor tags call a JavaScript function.

The 'catch 22' that I have is:

- `href="#"` makes the page jump to the top every time one of the anchor tags is clicked (very annoying)
- removing `href="#"` means that the cursor does not change as an anchor tag is hovered over nor does that anchor tag have the appearance of an anchor tag.

I know there is a way to handle this with JavaScript (possibly jQuery) but I don't recall how at the moment. However, I really prefer a **simpler HTML fix** (if one exists) that does not require me to get into JavaScript.

Edit:
"does not require me to *get into* JavaScript" == "does not require *extensive* changes in JavaScript."

Comment: You can just set `cursor: pointer;` on <a> tags if you need to (and other hover styles). This is CSS though, not HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler HTML fix for you: Personally speaking, for plain test links I just use `href=""`

For links that point to a javascript function I tend to use `href="javascript:;"`. Either way you'll stop the page jumping.

Answer (score 4):

In your javascript function you should `return false`, or with jquery you can use [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Example:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do something
});
```

Or in your case:

```
<a href=“#” onclick="foo();return false;">
```

Or change the href to `javascript:void(0)`:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="foo();">
```

Ideally, your link degrades without javascript, so the third option will usually be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

do return false after onclick or from within the foo() function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `event.preventDefault();` somewhere in your click event handler. In vanilla javascript, this can be done like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function foo(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // other code
  }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="foo(e);"></a>
```

Additionally, you can also return false:

```
<a href="#" onclick="foo();return false;/>
```

This can be also done in jQuery pretty simply:

```
$('.mylink').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // other code
});
```

The downside of using `return false;` is that is also prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM. If you don't care about event bubbling it's okay to use false, but personally I feel that it's better to use `event.preventDefault();` unless you specifically want to stop event bubbling as well.

Comment: Heh, I didn't even realize `preventDefault()` was vanilla javascript - shows how much I've been limping along with jQuery as my crutch! +1 good explanation.

Comment: jQuery does pass its own event object, but it's only to help with normalization across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    <style>
    a {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function foo() {
        alert('Hello World');
      }
    </script>
    <a onclick="foo();">Click Here</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Just adding the CSS and removing the `href` seems fine.